# How to construct a Regular Expression in Java Script for OR condition?

Tags: javascript, regex, datatables, fnfilter

I want to construct a regular expression in Javascript with 'OR' condition for me to input that into a `fnFilter()` function call to do column multi filtering.

Let's say I want to filter a column for values either A or B.

```
var string1 = 'A';
var string2 = 'B';
```

If I use '|' between these two strings, it's treated as bit wise OR operator.

```
oTable.fnFilter(string1 | string 2, columnIndex, true, false);
```

If I use '||' between these two strings, it's treated as logical OR operator.

```
oTable.fnFilter(string1 || string 2, columnIndex, true, false);
```

What I should insert or do more to make it work like a regular expression, which brings the meaning, either A or B, and filter the column for values either A or B?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
'(' + string1 + '|' + string2 + ')'
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful suggestion. I tried this in a simple java script application, and it works perfectly fine. But somehow Im unable to get it work in the fnFilter() function of DataTables plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could instance the `RegExp` object like so:

```
var filterRegEx = new RegExp(string1 + '|' + string2, 'g');
oTable.fnFilter(filterRegEx, columnIndex, true, false);
```

Comment: Thank you. This too worked in a java script application, which I tried. But when I take this to fnFilter function and apply it there, this doesn't work. It gives me a hint that the fnFilter function has issues recognizing the regular expression. It recognizes the inputs with bit wise and logical operators.